# html page outside iframe must call parent page

Tags: html, url, iframe, parent

Well, apparently there is no answer yet to the problem I have.
I made a website with an iframe.
In this iframe I display the pages activaded by the menu buttons.
Those pages are found by searchengines too. 
But without the website these pages are "naked".
I want the following.
If the "naked" page has been found, automatically a call has been made to the parent page to dress the "naked" page. So the whole website will be visible and not the "naked" page.
Thanks4thinking with me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to detect whether "iframed" child page is called directly, and if that's the case - redirect to the parent page. Below is a basic example how to do it in such child page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function checkIfInIframe() {
            if (window == window.parent) location.href = 'Parent.html';
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body onload="checkIfInIframe();">

    <!--Child Content-->

</body>
</html>
```

Here we call JavaScript function "checkIfInIframe" in page's body "onload" event. The code checks whether page is at top level (where it shouldn't be) or not. It does that by comparing "window" object to it's parent' If it's the same object - page redirects to it's parent. You can even pass parameters in a Query string in that redirect so parent would automatically know which page to open in the Iframe

Comment: No problem :) Please mark the response as Answer if it worked for you. Please let me know if you have any more questions/problems